# how to calculate number of leap years between two dates in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am doing report in SSRS, I need dataset column for calculating the number of leap years between two dates in t-SQL. I found the function for single input parameter whether it is the leap year or not but for my requirement two parameters in function or any t-SQL statement.

Thanks..waiting for anybody reply

Comment: What's the nature of these dates? Will they always be for a fixed day of the year? If not, how do you want to handle a start date that occurs in March or later of a leap year? Should that year count? And vice versa for an end date before 29th February of a leap year?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the reply. actually I got 2 different date time columns in my table. I want to count no. of Leap years between those two input columns date. It is from Year wise means January to Dec..thanks

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, I was wrong, leap year starts from March..any advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought, will add as another answer.

```
DECLARE @A DATE = '2008-03-23',
    @B DATE = '2012-04-20'

DECLARE @AM INT,@AY INT,@BM INT,@BY INT
SET @AM = DATEPART(MONTH,@A),   --3
    @AY = DATEPART(YEAR,@A),    --2008
    @BM = DATEPART(MONTH,@B),   --4
    @BY = DATEPART(YEAR,@B)     --2012

DECLARE @COUNT INT = 0

WHILE (@AY <= @BY)
BEGIN
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 
                (CASE   WHEN (@AY%4 = 0 AND @AY%100 !=0) OR @AY%400 = 0 
                        THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 END)
    SET @AY = @AY + 1
END

SET @COUNT = @COUNT + CASE WHEN @AM >= 3 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END

SELECT @A BEGIN_DATE,@Y END_DATE,@COUNT NO_OF_LEAP_YEARS
```

As I dont have an instance of sql server available now,I did not test the code..But you will get the an idea about what I was trying to achieve.
I declared @BM, in case you want to do the checking with the end month too..

Comment: Jithin, got one more problem with this code. It is working fine when it is Leap year and March or over month. But it taking Non-Leap years months also. For ex: start date: 2007-05-15 , end date: 2007-10-06 the Count showing -1. Can you please sort out for me..Thanks

Comment: with the above code declare dates as start date: 2007-05-15 , end date: 2007-10-06 you will get -1. Please check once.Thanks

Comment: @user3583912 I know this is 5 years to late, but see improved answer.

Answer (score 2):

Number of leap days between two dates.

```
DECLARE
    @StartDate DATETIME = '2000-02-28',
    @EndDate DATETIME = '2017-02-28'

SELECT ((CONVERT(INT,@EndDate-58)) / 1461 - (CONVERT(INT,@StartDate-58)) / 1461)
```

-58 to start counting from 1st March 1900 and / 1461 being the number of days between 29th Februaries.
NOTE: in Excel, the -58 would be -60 as 1st Jan 1900 in Excel is day 1 but in SQL is day zero and SQL doesn't recognise 29th Feb 1900 whereas Excel does.
ALSO NOTE:  This formula will go wrong every 400 years as every 400 years we skip a leap year.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @year int
SET @year = 2008
if (((@year % 4 = 0) AND (@year % 100 != 0)) OR (@year % 400 = 0))
print 'Leap year'
ELSE
print 'No'
```

Comment: mohan111, thanks for the reply but i want to count number of leap years between two dates. I think in your code we can enter only one year but i want to enter two dates and count of leap years between those dates..thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want to do with the first and last year depend on your date parameters.
Here is an example how to do it with the recursive query:

```
with cte as
(
     select YEAR('1900-01-01') as [year]
     union all
     select [year] + 1
     from    cte   
     where   [year] + 1 <= YEAR('2100-01-01')
 )
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM cte WHERE
           ([YEAR]%4=0) AND (([YEAR]%100<>0) OR ([YEAR]%400=0))
 OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34688)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Hope this too works.

```
DECLARE @X INT = 1590
DECLARE @Y INT = 1603

DECLARE @COUNT INT = 0,@Z INT = @X

WHILE (@X <= @Y)
BEGIN
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 
                (CASE   WHEN (@X%4 = 0 AND @X%100 !=0) OR @X%400 = 0 
                        THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 END)
    SET @X = @X + 1
END

SELECT @Z BEGIN_YEAR,@Y END_YEAR,@COUNT NO_OF_LEAP_YEARS
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Jithin, above code working fine but i want to include one more point here, if my Start date is started in March 2012 or later in that leap year it shouldn't consider as leap year. For Ex: 2008-03-01 to 214-05-01, the count should be 1. But according to above code its coming 2. it is considering 2008, 2012 as leap years. But my start date is in March 2008. I hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sql function based on some of the answers above that should do this -

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LeapDayCount]
(
    @StartDate as datetime,
    @EndDate as datetime
)
RETURNS int as
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StartYear int
    DECLARE @EndYear int
    DECLARE @Year int

    SELECT @StartYear = YEAR(@StartDate)
    SELECT @EndYear = YEAR(@EndDate)

    DECLARE @Count int

    SET @Count = 0

    SET @Year = @StartYear

    WHILE (@Year <= @EndYear)
    BEGIN
        SET @Count = @Count + 
                    (CASE WHEN (@Year%4 = 0 AND @Year%100 !=0) OR @Year%400 = 0 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

        SET @Year = @Year + 1
    END

    --remove one leap day if start date is a leap year but after february
    IF ((@StartYear%4 = 0 AND @StartYear%100 !=0) OR @StartYear%400 = 0) AND MONTH(@StartDate) > 2 SET @Count = @Count -1

        --remove one leap day if end date is a leap year but less than 29th Feb
    IF ((@EndYear%4 = 0 AND @EndYear%100 !=0) OR @EndYear%400 = 0) AND (MONTH(@EndDate) = 1 OR (MONTH(@EndDate) = 2 AND DAY(@EndDate) < 29)) SET @Count = @Count -1

RETURN @Count
END
```

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on the original answer

This has 2 improvements

- Fixed a bug relating to subtracting -1 when a start date is after feb EVEN when the start year is not a leap year
- Also the -1 function at the bottom should check the original start month NOT the changing 1.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION riskstore.GetLeapYearCount (@Start Date, @End Date)
> RETURNS INT
> AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @StartMonth INT = DATEPART(MONTH,@Start)
>     DECLARE @StartYear INT = DATEPART(YEAR,@Start)
>     DECLARE @OriginalStartYear INT = DATEPART(YEAR,@Start)
>     DECLARE @EndMonth INT = DATEPART(MONTH,@End)
>     DECLARE @EndYear INT = DATEPART(YEAR,@End)
>     DECLARE @COUNT INT = 0
>     WHILE (@StartYear <= @EndYear)
>     BEGIN
>         SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 
>                 (CASE   WHEN (@StartYear%4 = 0 AND @StartYear%100 !=0) OR @StartYear%400 = 0 
>                         THEN 1 
>                         ELSE 0 END)
>         SET @StartYear = @StartYear + 1
>     END
>     SET @COUNT = @COUNT + CASE WHEN @StartMonth >= 3 AND ((@OriginalStartYear%4 = 0 AND @OriginalStartYear%100 !=0) OR @OriginalStartYear%400 = 0) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
>     RETURN (@COUNT)
> END
> ```